# What does .v() mean in soot library?

Tags: java, soot

I work with soot library.

In different examples I see `.v()` method, for example `Jimple.v()`, `scene.v()`, ... .

Now I want ask what does it mean? Specially in `Jimple.v()`.

Comment: Tried to read the JavaDoc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) implementation in soot.

E.g. `Jimple.v()` returns the global single instance of `Jimple` class. Same for the `Scene` class.

Reference: [soot / Creating a class from scratch](https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki/Creating-a-class-from-scratch).